# Name Range in an array

Tags: excel, vba

I have a variant variable which contains two name ranges. I try to copy the range using the name of the range stored in the variable but i do not know how to do it. Please see below my code. Any suggestions?

```
Dim tbl2 As Range
Dim tablearray2 As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

tablearray2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2:C3") **<--- Here i store the name of the ranges in the tablearray2 variable**

'The tablearray2 now contains the following values: Table1, Table2 which are the names of two different ranges.

Set tbl2 = tablearray2(2,1)

tbl2.copy

End Sub
```

**Thank you for your help**

Comment: So you want to assign `tbl2` to be the cell C3? That's probably not going to work because the array is storing the values of those cells, not the cells themselves.

Comment: Seen the commented line now, so perhaps `Set tbl2 = range(tablearray2(2,1))`?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response. No, the cell C3 has the value "Table1". Table1 is the name of range i.e the range A4:C3 has the name Table1. So what i want to do is: set tbl2=[Table1]. But because i have a lot of name ranges i want to call from the array. I am sorry if i confused you.

Comment: No my fault for not reading properly. See my second comment.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can copy the range. How can i paste the whole range in another cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a small example, including the paste bit.

```
Sub x()

Dim tbl2 As Range
Dim tablearray2 As Variant

tablearray2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2:C3")

Set tbl2 = Range(tablearray2(2, 1)) 'contents of C3 = "Table2"

tbl2.Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A5") 'paste range to A5

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Following the previous question I try to copy the table to word document, but i get that error:

Run-time error'91:

Object variable or With block variable not set

See my code below:
Private Sub commandButton2_Click()

```
Dim tbl2 As Range
Dim wordapp As Word.Application
Dim mydoc As Word.Document
Dim wordtable As Word.Table
Dim tablearray2 As Variant
Dim bokkar As Variant


bookar = Array("PhoneNumber", "Occupation")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

'fnopenworddoc <--- this is a function which open the word document

tablearray2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2:C3")

Set tbl2 = Range(tablearray2(2, 1))
tbl2.copy
'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K4").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll


mydoc.Bookmarks("Occupation").Range.PasteExcelTable _
       LinkedtoExcel:=False, _
          WordFormatting:=False, _
            RTF:=False

Set wordtable = mydoc.Tables(1)
      wordtable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)

End Sub
```